# JQ sidebar animate

Tags: jquery, sidebar

The error is that you need to press 2 click first "Click Here To Toggle" to work good.How can I fix it to work with one click?

[my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ktk7z/1027/)

```
   $(function(){
   $('.mobicon').click(function(){
            if($('#aside-left').is(':hidden')){
                 $('#aside-left').show();
                $('#aside-left').animate({'width':'100%'},'slow');
            }
            else{
                $('#aside-left').animate({'width':'0%'},'slow',function(){
                    $('#aside-left').hide();
                });
            }


        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default display value for the **aside-left** element is not defined (the default value on Windows 10 with Chrome/IE/FireFox is block while you need none). According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> The display CSS property specifies the type of rendering box used for an element. In HTML, default display property values are taken from behaviors described in the HTML specifications or from the browser/user default stylesheet. The default value in XML is inline.

Add it to your css:

```
 #aside-left {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #111;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The snippet:

```js
$('.mobicon').click(function() {
    if ($('#aside-left').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#aside-left').show();
        $('#aside-left').animate({'width': '100%'}, 'slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#aside-left').animate({'width': '0%'}, 'slow', function () {
            $('#aside-left').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

```css
#aside-left {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #111;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mobicon{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="mobicon">Click Here To Toggle</div>
<div id="aside-left">sidebar content here</div>
```